# Jquery slider fault

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've be working on a website which already has CSS elements and have tried to put a slider in a small css box, but isn't working for some reason. I'm using Jquery from Google API which i linked in the head tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Home Page</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <!---Link to Jquery Library--->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

function slider() {
$(".slider#1").show("fade",500);
$(".slider#1").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);

var sc=$(".slider img").size();
var count=2;

setinterval(function(){
$(".slider#"+count).show("slide",{direction:'right'},500);
$(".slider#"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);

if (count ==sc){
    count=1;
    }else{
    count=count+1;

      }

     },6500);

}
</script>
  </head>

<body onload="slider();">

<div id="RightColContainer">
<div id="RightColContent">
<div class="slider">
<img id="1" src="Slider/Image/Image1.jpg" border="0" alt="Razer Keyboard"/>
<img id="2" src="Slider/Image/Image2.jpg" border="0" alt="Microsoft Office"/>
<img id="3" src="Slider/Image/Image3.jpg" border="0" alt="Razer Mouse"/>
 </div>
    </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your code inside `$(window).load(function() {....})` and remove the function `slider` from `onload` function of your `body`.

```
$(window).load(function () {
        $(".slider#1").show("fade", 500);
        $(".slider#1").delay(5500).hide("slide", {
            direction: 'left'
        }, 500);

        var sc = $(".slider img").size();
        var count = 2;

        setinterval(function () {
            $(".slider#" + count).show("slide", {
                direction: 'right'
            }, 500);
            $(".slider#" + count).delay(5500).hide("slide", {
                direction: 'left'
            }, 500);

            if (count == sc) {
                count = 1;
            } else {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }, 6500);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this still isn't working, i deleted the onload from the body tag and pasted this code; nothing happened. Am i missing something?

Comment: You need to have a space here `$(".slider #"+count)` to select the child images of your div. Currently `$(".slider#"+count)` which does not has any space.